# Saying "to do someone dirt" in different ways

Tags: word-choice

I looked it up in some dictionaries and delved out a good row of words having much common in meaning on the first gaze. But, in reality, I got stuck being unable to discern if they are applicable to my case at all.

Could native speakers take in and accept these expressions as usable to convey the idea of "doing someone dirt"?

1. to do someone [all that] muck;
2. to do someone [all that] stuff;
3. to do someone [all that] filth;
4. to do someone [all that] guck;
5. to do someone [all that] beastliness;
6. to do someone [all that] horridness;
7. to do someone [all that] hideousness;
8. to do someone [all that] crap.

Especially in interrogations/exclamations like: "Why did you do all that muck, crap, hideousness, horridness, stuff etc to me?"

Comment: Are you maybe thinking of ["do someone dirty"](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/do-someone-dirty)?

Comment: @stangdon I wouldn't say for sure whether it means the same what I intended to express. Maybe they are close. It is not fully about slandering someone (in some cases it may be). I was saying that "doing someone dirt" was "doing mean, vile, dishonourable things to someone".

Comment: I don't know what all of these comments and answers meant to say about the original expression. I've never heard any expression on your bullet list, but I've definitely heard "Do someone dirt," meaning something like "To mistreat someone." See https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/do+you+dirt.

Comment: @Chaim The expressions on my bullet list are no way to be regarded idiomatic. I simply concocted them and wanted to make out if the native speakers might take them in and accept some of them, maybe (I just conjectured that, for example, "why did you do all that horridness/hideousness/ stuff/ muck/ guck/crap etc to me?" might be acceptable in some emotional situations). But all in all, downvoting questions here doesn't add up to me, frankly speaking.

Answer (score 0):

First, “play a [dirty] trick on someone” is an idiom that means to fool or embarrass someone. It is not “do a trick on someone,” and it is certainly not “do someone a trick.”

Second, none of your alternatives is a synonym for “trick.” Thus, none of your alternatives corresponds to “play a trick on,” and in fact none is even idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

None of these would be used in English.  The closest to any of these that would ever be used is "to do someone mischief".  The other expressions are not standard English.